# MacOs Photos project extension. Added photo detection

Tags: swift, macos, photo

In debug mode I create a project with my project extension app (in 10.13). Then I close it by pressing "Done". Then I drag a photo to this project (to icon in "My Projects") and drop it there (with "+" icon). And then, If I open my project, I cant't detect the adding of that new photo to.

While opening project, OS calls the only method:

```
func resumeProject(with extensionContext: PHProjectExtensionContext, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)
```

but with `extensionContext` I can't get the information about added new photo!
`extensionContext.inputItems`    has 0 items count
`extensionContext.project`   has nothing helpful too

the `photoLibraryDidChange(_:)` is not called in this case

Thanks for any help or guidance!

------ after edit ------
example of adding a photo to the project:
[image: example of adding a photo to the project]

Comment: Never did a Photos extension in macOS, only with iOS. (1) You're confusing me (at least) by your use of the word "icon". I'm assuming you are dealing with an app icon, right? (2) Photos extensions work in **one** direction only. Photos >> your extension, via the "..." button. Open Photos, select an image, choose to edit, and tap the "..." button. Thus, Photos >> your app. There is NO way to "drag" anything into your app. (Hopefully I'm wrong and macOS operates differently.)

Comment: (1) More correct would be to say "icon_name", ok )) - see pic. (2) On MacOs there are two ways - create the project with some photos and add photos by drag-drop to the project's icon_name while the project is closed... so unfortunately I have to know it... but thank you anyway!